# Android parsing plist to document

Tags: android, parsing, plist

I'm trying to parse an iPhone plist file to use it with xpath and xpathexpression.

plist example:

```
<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>00</key>
        <dict>
            <key>pkw</key>
            <dict>
                <key>gas</key>
                <integer>0</integer>
                <key>diesel</key>
                <dict>
                    <key>ohne</key>
                    <integer>0</integer>
                    <key>pm01</key>
                    <integer>0</integer>
                    <key>pm0</key>
                    <integer>0</integer>
                    <key>pm1</key>
                    <integer>0</integer>
                    <key>pm2</key>
                    <integer>0</integer>
                    <key>pm3</key>
                    <integer>0</integer>
                    <key>pm4</key>
                    <integer>0</integer>
                    <key>pm5</key>
                    <integer>4</integer>
                </dict>
                <key>otto</key>
                <integer>0</integer>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</plist>
```

With the following code I'm getting a `SAXParserException`

> name expected (position:START_TAG @3:41 in java.io.InputStreamReader@43e395f0)

```
    DocumentBuilderFactory builderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
builderFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);
DocumentBuilder builder = null;
try {
    builder = builderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
} catch (ParserConfigurationException e1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e1.printStackTrace();
}

Document document = null;
try {
    document = builder.parse(getApplicationContext().getResources().openRawResource(R.xml.finedust));
} catch (NotFoundException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (SAXException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Maybe someone has an idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is, that you are trying to load the plist xml document from the res/xml/ folder (`R.xml.finedust`) as a raw resource.

You should put your xml file inside the res/raw/ folder (res/raw/findedust.xml), and access it by `R.raw.finedust`.

So your `document` initialization will be:

```
document = builder.parse(getApplicationContext().getResources().
    openRawResource(R.raw.finedust));
```

This way it will work!

**Deprecated**

You have 4 `<dict>` tags opened but only 3 of them have the matching close tags.

One of your `<dict>` tag - probably the first - is not closed! You should check your input, and when you figure it out, close it, then it will parse the xml.

The parsing cannot be done unless the document is well-formed (not necessarily valid though).

Comment: Eclipse doesn't display any error if i open the plist file. Notepad++ says its well formed too. The code formating block doesn't display the rest of my example.

Comment: All of your xml code is visible, and it can be viewed by clicking on the edit link too. It would be wierd anyway, that you have the root closed, but not a child tag because of formatting. Just count your open `<dict>` tags and the close `</dict>` tags. They don't match, so there's no way a parser can process it. If you missed a tag when pasting it, please correct your xml source.

Comment: Thats because i copied a part of 9600 lines.

Comment: ok, then at least note where should we imagine the missing `</dict>` tag? Say, at the end of your document, before closing the root tag? Also, it would help if you could share a link where we can take a look at the actual xml you are dealing with. thank you!

Comment: Now the example is well formed. The tag at the end, before closing the root tag was missing.

Comment: Thank you! could you please also share a link that points to your actual xml? From the error it seams that misses some attribute/value.

Comment: i've uploaded it. you can download it here: https://rapidshare.com/files/458476132/test.plist

Comment: well i've renamed the file with the ending .xml and its now in the raw folder. But it takes 30 sec to parse the file :/ is there a way to use xpath without parsing the xml file? just loading it ?

Comment: no, there is no :(. but if it's not necessary to have that huge xml on your device for your application to run, i'd suggest to have it on the server, (eventually refresh it and) parse it there, and pass only the useful data (already parsed data) to your application via eg. a http request's response. at my end with debugging on, the parsing took 25 secs too, so it's not that good practice to deal with in inside the ui thread.

Comment: If parsing this data is an occasional task, and not necessarily runs at application start, then you could use an `AsyncTask` (or other threading technique) for it to run in background, and so you can keep your file locally on the device. For further reference please see the [Android Developers' Painless Threading](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html) article

Comment: well i want to use this xml file because the iphone app uses this too. i want to parse the file in background while, when the user is busy with understanding the activity. i will have a look your posted link. thanks for your help :-)